# python: running a thread based on a flag

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm new to python: I've a python module that states whether a hardware device is Enabled or not (Python Module A).I've another python module that defines a thread that takes care of collecting the hardware device statistics(Python Module B).

But I need to collect statistics only when the hardware device is enabled.
For this, I started my thread in Python Module A but need to control the run method of thread from here.

Any suggestions! Please help!

Note: These modules run as robot framework libraries. So, according to the test cases, if a hardware device is enabled successfully, only then collect statistics otherwise don't.

Comment: Can't you decide whether start the thread or not according to the hardware device status? I've understood that you start the thread anyway, and then decide to collect statistics (or not)

Comment: Hi Magicleon, these modules run as robot framework libraries. So, according to the test cases, if a hardware device is enabled successfully, only then collect statistics otherwise don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For start you can sync them on empty file created from module A (put the creation in **init**() and removal in **del**() in case of Class init of just creat/remove method in start/end of the thread run method) so B will know that device is up and delete it when device is off.But if both threads started from the same process,shared object would do the trick.Your code would be useful for more specific answer.